# Elastic Search java client: Sort on string field is not returning correct result

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I am using elastic search java api. I want to get sorted list based on field say jobCategory in ascending order:

```
SearchRequestBuilder builder = ESClientUtil.getClient().prepareSearch(config.getESIndexName())

FieldSortBuilder sortBuilder = SortBuilders.fieldSort(sortBy).order(sortOrder);

builder.addSort(sortBuilder);
```

Above code is not returning the sorted list based on `jobCategory`. `jobCategory` is string data type field.

Comment: Just a guess.Have you assigned `SortBuilders.fieldSort("jobCategory").order(SortOrder.ASC);` to `sortBuilder`. I can't see that in above code.

Comment: yes Richa, I have assigned sortBuilder to SearchRequestBuilder.

Comment: ... and what it returns? What value of sortOrder?